# Как закрыть task в jira скриптом

Tags: python, jira

имеется такой код

```py
from atlassian import Jira

jira = Jira(
    url='localhost:1234',
    username='admin',
    password='admin',
)
jira.issue_transition(issue_key, status='ВЫПОЛНЕНА')
```

все бы ничего, но получаю такую ошибку

```
    return self.post(url, data=data)
  File "C:\Users\roman\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\jira-cli-fw9jSViC-py3.10\lib\site-packages\atlassian\rest_client.py", line 336, in post
    response = self.request(
  File "C:\Users\roman\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\jira-cli-fw9jSViC-py3.10\lib\site-packages\atlassian\rest_client.py", line 260, in request
    self.raise_for_status(response)
  File "C:\Users\roman\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\jira-cli-fw9jSViC-py3.10\lib\site-packages\atlassian\rest_client.py", line 497, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(error_msg, response=response)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: Необходимо заполнить поле Story Points
```

Comment: Очевидно, необходимо заполнить поле Story Points) Что конкретно не понятно?

Comment: Мне непонятно где оно задается, это должно быть особенности апи иди это заложено в библиотеке?

Comment: Это ответ сервера, самой jira. Скорее всего нужно или руками в таске проставить, или через api

Comment: Я пробую получить информацию через postman, но такого поля там нет. Я наделялся что должен быть какой то флаг или иной параметр

Comment: Метод update_issue_field: https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/jira.html#manage-issues . По аналогии с примером, только имя поля будет Story Points, и значение числовое. И это все равно по идее должно вручную проставляться в самой задаче. Стори поинты назначаются разработчиками (до начала ее фактического выполнения), это прогнозируемое количество единиц трудозатрат на задачу. См. например https://habr.com/ru/articles/489500/

Comment: Возможно обязательность этого поля как-то отключается в настройках джиры, но это я уже не знаю.